# DB2 Database Compare Tool

Tags: db2, database-comparison

Does anyone know of a product similar to Red-Gate's SQL Compare that targets DB2? I am aware of [DBDiff](http://www.dkgas.com/dbdiff.htm) but need a tool that compares schema and stored procedures.

**Update:** After some more google searching I will try using either [UDB Workbench](http://mingsoftware.com/udbworkbench/overview.html) and [DB Solo](http://www.dbsolo.com/schema_comparison.html).

Comment: Which one did you end up choosing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Embarcadero Change Manager (I guess it is free tool)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more: http://www.sqledt.com/ - does a few more things than simple db compare.